Change Shape Colour in Excel based on another sheet cell value
I am trying below code to a normal module to change shape color based on whether Sheet1.Range("A1") has a value and if it has then change colour of a shape which is on another sheet (like Sheet2).
Sub Change_Shape_Color()
  If Sheet1.Range("A1") <> "" Then
    Sheet2.Shapes.Range(Array("Shape_1")).ShapeRange.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 128, 0)
  Else
    Sheet2.Shapes.Range(Array("Shape_1")).ShapeRange.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
  End If
End Sub

But Excel shows a

Runtime Error (438)
Object doesn't support this property or method.`


Remove ShapeRange and directly change ShapeSheet2.Shapes.Range(Array("Shape_1")).Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 128, 0).

Sheet2.Shapes("Shape_1").ShapeRange.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = IIf(Sheet1.Range("A1") <> "",  RGB(0, 128, 0), vbRed)

@TimWilliams: Neither Shapes (as in Shapes("Shape_1") nor ShapeRanges (as in Shapes.Range(Array("Shape_1"))) have a property ShapeRange.

Fixing typo - Sheet2.Shapes("Shape_1").Fill.ForeColor.RGB = IIf(Sheet1.Range("A1") <> "",  RGB(0, 128, 0), vbRed) thanks @FunThomas

You can set the properties (eg ForeColor) of a single shape or for multiple shapes at once.
(1) To set it for a single shape, use something like this:
Sheet2.Shapes("Shape_1").Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 128, 0)

You can also assign the shape first to a variable of type Shape and use that:
Dim sh as Shape
Set sh = Sheet2.Shapes("Shape_1")
sh.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 128, 0)

(2) To set if for multiple shapes, use
Sheet2.Shapes.Range(Array("Shape_1", "Shape_2")).Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 128, 0)

This works also if your array contains only one shape, it's just a little overkill compared using the syntax of the first example.
Sheet2.Shapes.Range(Array("Shape_1")).Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 128, 0)

If you want to assign an Array of Shapes to a variable, use the type ShapeRange:
Dim shapes As ShapeRange
Set shapes = Sheet2.shapes.Range(Array("Shape_1", "Shape_2"))
shapes.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 128, 0)

(3) If you want to set properties of shapes that were selected by the user, you can use Selection.ShapeRange:
Selection.ShapeRange.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 128, 0)

However, this will give you a runtime error when no shape is selected.

To explain the error you got:
Sheet2.Shapes.Range(Array("Shape_1")) is an object of type ShapeRange (having only one shape, but that doesn't matter). A ShapeRange has no property ShapeRange, so that's giving you the error 438.
Simply removing this "ShapeRange" would fix the error: Sheet2.Shapes.Range(Array("Shape_1")).Fill.ForeColor.RGB - this is the syntax shown at (2). However, if I were you, for a single shape I would switch to the syntax (1).
